# Parse Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I parse a hash in ROR?
I have a hash in string format(enclosed by double quotes) and i need to parse them to a valid hash.

eg.

```
input_hash = "{"name" => "john"}"
```

desired

```
output_hash = {"name" => "john"}
```

Comment: You could `eval` it. But you didn't hear this from me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong approach. String representation of a ruby hash is not a good way to serialise data. It is well structured, and definitely possible to get it back to a ruby hash (`eval`), but it's extremely dangerous and can give an attacker who has control over the input string full control over your system.

Approach the problem from a different angle. Look for where the string gets stored and change the code there instead. Store it for example as JSON. Then it can easily and safely be parsed back to a hash and can also be sent to systems running on something that is not ruby.